# Generic callback methods(@PostLoad..) for inherited entity classes - JPA EclipseLink

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa, entity, eclipselink

My entity class hierarchy is as follows..  **ClassB** which extends **ClassA** which extends abstract mappedsuperclass **AbstractClass**

**AbstractClass**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractClass implements Serializable 
{

}
```

**ClassA**

```
@Table(name = "TABLE_ONE")
@SecondaryTable(name = "TABLE_TWO", 
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="Type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("ClassA")
public class ClassA extends AbstractClass
{
    @Column(name = "CLASSA_XML")
    private String ClassAXML;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void covertObjectToXml()
    {
        this.ClassAXML= JAXBUtilities.marshal(Object);
    }

    @PostLoad
    public void convertXmlToObject()
    {
       //does unmarshal  
    }
}
```

**ClassB**

```
@DiscriminatorValue("ClassB")
public class ClassB extends ClassA 
{
    @Column(name = "CLASSB_XML", table = "TABLE_TWO")
    private String ClassBXML;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void covertObjectToXml()
    {
        this.ClassAXML= JAXBUtilities.marshal(Object);
    }

    @PostLoad
    public void convertXmlToObject()
    {
       //does unmarshal  
    }
}
```

Problem : when i persist using ClassB entity. ClassA callback methods are not called and value in my classAXml attribute is not persisted.

Is there anyway to generalize **callback method**(i.e covertObjectToXml and convertXmlToObject) for my inherited entity class structure.. so that **when i persist using 
both ClassA and ClassB individually**, my callback methods are called respectively based on inheritance and their values can be persisted.

Note:

1. I have removed the callback methods from ClassA and generalize it in
   classB and persist but my requirement is mainly individual
   persistent of classA and ClassB.
2. my call back methods should not be in mapedSuperClass i.e AbstractClass.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities to reuse the callback code from `ClassA` in `ClassB`:

**I.** The best/most elegant way is to move the whole code to a new class, say `MyEntityListeners` 
 and then to use the [@EntityListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityListeners.html) annotation on your entity classes like

```
@EntityListeners(class=MyEntityListeners.class)
public class ClassB extends ClassA {
  .....
}

public class MyEntityListeners {
    @PrePersist
    public void onPrePersist(Object entity) {
        //logic with entity (check the class of the entity or you can use `ClassA` instead of `Object`)
    }
}
```

Please note that the `EntityListeners` are [inherited](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html#d0e3053) in the subclasses from superclasses, so you do not need to do anything in `ClassB` if the EntiyListeners are already defined in `ClassA` (but you can add additional EntityListeners in ClassB, that are not in ClassA). For excluding **all** EntityListeners from the hierarchy you can use [@ExcludeSuperclassListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ExcludeSuperclassListeners.html)

**II.** If you have less callback methods and a small hierarchy tree, than you could overwrite and re-annotate every callback from `ClassA` also in `ClassB` like

```
...
public class ClassB extends ClassA {
  ......
  @Override
  @PrePersist
  public void myCallback() {
        super.myCallback();
  }
  ......
}
```

Comment: Using super is working for individual persistent of both ClassA and ClassB. But i have a doubt, generalize using EntityListener is good for me because i may use this in 'n' number of entity classes because these two methods are common for all. Now my problem is i have to pass a class instance into this callback methods(i.e MyEntityListeners) to set the column value on their respective entity.. can u suggest anything for this problem.

Comment: That is not a problem: you get an instance of your entity in the callback methods in `MyEntityListeners`. Also EntityListeners are inherited. See my chnaged response.